# C# program for months

Tags: c#

i am strugling with an exercise. I am a beginer and dont know where to start. I am asked to create a console program that if you give it a number between 1 and 12 it must give you the corresponding month name and if you give it the name of the month it should give you the number of the month. Please help with the code. It should be done using an ARRAY. Thank you.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. what have you tried?

Comment: Well, what do you have so far? If the answer is *nothing*, then probably the first thing you need is an array holding the month names as strings.

Comment: Take a look at `System.Globalization.CultureInfo`, specifically the `DateTimeFormat` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat.aspx

Comment: "Please help with the code" That's what we're here for. But, you understand, we're here to help with *your* code, not write it for you. What have you written so far?

Comment: I updated my answer to include the array part in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you're learning, I guess... they may just be demonstrating a switch(intMonth) type thing, so:

```
switch(intMonth)
{        
         case 1:   
            return "January";
            break;                  
         case 2:   
            return "February";
            break;
         ....
}
```

Or as mentioned, make use of DateTime...

There's many many ways to do it... I guess you need to select the right way... most efficient way... so, depends on your assignment.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you will learn something from this code, because if it gets copied to a USB stick and givent to the teacher without even taking  alook to it, I will be very mad, come to your home and do a mess! :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int iMonth = -1;

            // loop until iMonth is 0
            while (iMonth != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please insert a number from 1 to 12 and press enter. Enter 0 to exit.");
                string sMonth = Console.ReadLine();

                // try to get a number from the string
                if (!int.TryParse(sMonth, out iMonth))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a number.");
                    iMonth = -1; // so we continue the loop
                    continue;
                }

                // exit the program
                if (iMonth == 0) break;

                // not a month
                if (iMonth < 1 || iMonth > 12) {
                    Console.WriteLine("The number must be from 1 to 12.");
                    continue;
                }

                // get the name of the month in the language of the OS
                string monthName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(iMonth);
                Console.WriteLine("The name of the month is " + monthName);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

If your teacher expects a custom provided name then you can use the switch statement in the last part:

```
switch (iMonth)
{        
         case 1:   
            Console.WriteLine("January");
            break;                  
         case 2:   
            Console.WriteLine("February");
            break;
         // add more
}
```

If he expects an array exercise then you can declare an array with all the strings and use that:

```
string[] monthNames = new string[] {
  "January",
  "February",
  // add more
};
```

and use this to get the name:

```
Console.WriteLine(monthNames[iMonth]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like that :

**String to Int Month**

**Code :**

```
Datetime.Parse(Monvalue + "/1/2011").ToString("MM")
```

**Like :**

```
Datetime.Parse("January/1/2011").ToString("MM")
```

**Retrun :**
01

Int to String Month

**Code :**

```
Datetime.Parse( Monvalue +"/9/2011").ToString("MMMMM")
```

**Like :**

```
Datetime.Parse("1/9/2011").ToString("MMMMM")
```

**Retrun :**
"January"

Before this you should handle wrong cases.I hope its help to you

Answer (score 0):

As Ernest suggested, take a look at the [DateTimeFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat.aspx) property within System.Globalization.CultureInfo.  What you're looking for is a method called GetMonthName().  The number passed into GetMonthName() is a numerical representation of that month.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Give me an integer between 1 and 12, and I will give you the month");

            int monthInteger = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            DateTime newDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, monthInteger, 1);

            Console.WriteLine("The month is: " + newDate.ToString("MMMM"));
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Give me a month name (ex: January), and I will give you the month integer");

            string monthName = Console.ReadLine();

            monthInteger = DateTime.ParseExact(monthName + " 1, " + DateTime.Now.Year, "MMMM d, yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month;

            Console.WriteLine("The month integer is " + monthInteger);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i understand your coding and will be able to complete the exercise. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The task of translating between numbers and names is quite trivial, so how you do it depends on what kind of language elements you are currently learning.

You can divide the problem into several sub-task, like determining if the input is a number of a name, picking the right conversion based on that, and the two different ways of doing the conversion. Each sub-task can be solved in several different ways.

To examine the input you could compare it to month names, and if none of them matches assume that it's a number, or you could use `Int32.TryParse` to try to parse the input as a number, and if that fails assume that it's a month name.

The most basic way of doing the conversion would be a lot of `if` statements. You could also use a switch, use an array of month names, or use dictionaries for the separate lookups.

Answer (score 0):

```
private string[] months = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr" };
public string GetMonth(int x)
{
    if(x > 0  && x < months.Length)
        return months[x];
    else
        return "";
}
```